# Font Awesome in HR

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am not even sure if this is possible but can I use font awesome icon in an HR:after?

I am trying the below, but i just get a square no icon?

```
hr{
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    text-align: center;
}
hr:after {
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    content: '\e800';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    top: -0.7em;  
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    background: white;
}
```

I have also created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4gZeg/

Comment: It works with other content values.. http://jsfiddle.net/PSLXw/ .. I'm not sure what `\e800` is suppose to be

Comment: Building on what @JoshC noted, perhaps you meant `\f0e8` for your `content`? It is the only other font-awesome 3 property with `e8`. http://jsfiddle.net/JFphx/

Comment: Uggghhh thanks guys i copy and pasted incorrectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `'\e800'` icon exists.

For example: `content: '\f08d';` works fine